# Vue + Vuetify + Axios + Django : CRUD data table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am trying to build a Vuetify CRUD using AXIOS. I am able to do CRUD operations, but am not able to display the newly added data till the page is refreshed. When I select edit, I am not able to see the existing data while editing. The editable dialog box shows empty.
Please help me if to resolve this.

Here is my script

```
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
import { getAPI } from '../axios-api'
// import DataService from "../services/DataService";
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      dialog: false,
      dialogDelete: false,
      headers: [
        { text: 'ID', align: 'start', value: 'id',},
        { text: 'Length', value: 'size' },
        { text: 'Weight', value: 'weight' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
      ],
      info: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        ID: '',
        Weight: 0,
        Length: 0,
      },
      defaultItem: {
        name: '',
        Weight: 0,
        Length: 0,
      },
    }),
    components:{
            Navbar
        },

    computed: {
      formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
      },
    },

    methods: {
      initialize () {
        getAPI.get('calibration/sizeweight')
        .then(response => {
        this.info = response.data
      })
      },

      editItem (item) {
        this.editedIndex = this.info.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
        this.dialog = true
      },

      deleteItem (item) {
        this.editedIndex = this.info.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
        this.dialogDelete = true
      },

      deleteItemConfirm () {
        this.info.splice(this.editedIndex, 1)
        this.closeDelete()
        getAPI.delete('calibration/sizeweight/'+this.editedItem.id)
        .then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
        })
      },

      close () {
        this.dialog = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        })
      },

      closeDelete () {
        this.dialogDelete = false
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        })
      },

      save () {
        if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
          Object.assign(this.info[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
          getAPI.put('calibration/sizeweight/'+this.editedItem.ID,{id:this.editedItem.ID ,weight:this.editedItem.Weight,size:this.editedItem.Length})
          .then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            this.initialize()
          })
        } else {
          this.info.push(this.editedItem)
          getAPI.post('calibration/sizeweight',{id:this.editedItem.ID ,weight:this.editedItem.Weight,size:this.editedItem.Length})
          .then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
            this.initialize()
          })
          .catch(error => { console.log(error.response.data)})
        }
        this.close()
      },
    },

    watch: {
      dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
      },
      dialogDelete (val) {
        val || this.closeDelete()
      },
    },

    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },


  }
</script>
```

Comment: If your CRUD methods are working fine you just need to use your initialize() function to update the array of items you are displaying. For example in the deleteItemConfirm() call your initialize() at the end.

Comment: Calling initialize() after create, update or delete will make the vue to hit the server and db each and every time, which is not and performance may be effected right? So is there a way, as I create, update or delete, dynamically the data in datatable to change without hitting the db?

Comment: When I click on edit, I am not able to know on which row data I clicked. As the dialog window doesn't show the data to be be edited and everything will be empty, is there a way to update this? So when I click on edit item, the row data that selected will be shown in the edit dialog Box